# Rails: show list of one controller inside of another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a "Resources" controller and on the index I can find a list of "Articles" and "Downloads", each of which is its own controller.

```
  <% @resource.each do |resource| %>
   <h4><%= resource.article.title %></h4>
   <h4><%= resource.article.description %></h4>
   <%= link_to "Read More...", article(article) %>
 <% end %>
```

And I made the association on the models like this:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :resource
end

class Download < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :resource
end

class Resource < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :articles
 has_many :downloads
end
```

How can I call the list of Articles and Downloads inside the Resources view, and link to them?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate over them:

```
  <% @resource.each do |resource| %>
    <% resource.articles.each do |article| %> 
       <h4><%= resource.article.title %></h4>
       <h4><%= resource.article.description %></h4>
       <%= link_to "Read More...", article(article) %>
    <% end %>
    #ADD same code for downloads here
 <% end %>
```